# Driver for a zebra GK420d label printer

Tags: drivers, printing

Hi everyone plz can someone help me i am looking for the Ubuntu 16.04 printer driver for a zebra GK420g label printer. I have been looking for driver for about 3 monts and i cant find it

Answer (score 7):

Zebra does not provide a driver for use on Linux/Unix or Mac OS X operating systems but instead suggests the use of the Common Unix Printing System (CUPS) driver.

Currently the CUPS printer driver supports all Zebra based ZPL, EPL1, EPL2,  and CPCL printers.  Kiosk (KPL language) support is expected in the 1.6 version of CUPS.

They do provide [extensive documentation](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/mac-linux-or-unix-driver-suggestions-for-zebra-printers.html) on configuring printers using CUPS.

> **To Install or Add a Zebra Printer**
>
> Using Safari for MAC or Mozilla for Linux OS’s enter either http://localhost:631/ or http://127.0.0.1:631/ to access the CUPS driver.
>
> On the MAC OS and some Linux versions it is built-in directly.  The following examples are all based on the 1.4.2 version of the CUPS driver which requires installation of the Snow Leopard MAC OS. The CUPS contributors made significant changes to the 1.4.# interface compared to previous 1.3.# versions.  Zebra was present in 1.3.# versions and once you get to the Zebra printer setup the options are basically the same.
>
> From the Home screen select Adding Printers and Classes

Comment: your answer is better. well done.

Comment: @tatsu and I only just started ;-)

Comment: Tanks for your help just one more thing the software i want to use (Poswizard) is a Point of Sale software made for windows xp, 7 and up to print barcodes it uses a  .lbl file to print on a label format (30mm x 40mm) label i got the software working using wine bat i cant workout how to get ot printing on a label printer 100% of you have any label templates that i can use i will really appreciate your help